# Disable badge count on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, android, mobilepush-android

I'm using 7.2.0 version of marketing cloud sdk plugin. Is there a way to disable the badge count on Android?

Comment: have you reviewed the github yet? https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/application-badging/application-badging.html

Comment: Hello @EazyE, I'm trying to disable it for android platform. I've just updated the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to provide an iOS link, have you reviewed this link https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Comment: No worries, yes I've reviewed this link, but not sure on how to implement it with the MC-Cordova-Plugin.